# Coreect drivers for ATI Raedon hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop with i7, and hybrid graphics(Intel HD 4000 with 2GB ATI Raedon HD 8730M. As expected, it ran into overheating problems when installing Ubuntu. Thats because of the missing graphics drivers. Where do I get the graphics drivers for my laptop, (which uses hybrid graphics, mind you). Can I use the fglrx-updates, or the proprietary driver or something else? Please help. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend installing the drivers from the AMD website ([here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)) and download and install a version that works with your kernel and your version of X.

You have to be careful when updating though, as kernel and X updates break the drivers.

To get the Linux Kernel version, type `uname -r` in a terminal.

To find your version of X, type `X -version` (yes, one - and not two)

(I've had occasional problems with the ones in the repos for some reason)